# Scaling tikz graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, arrows

I have a graph made with Tikz, it looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to make it more clear which edge "xx"s belong to. How can this be done?

First of, I have tried scaling the entire tikzimage as I would like it to be as wide as the page, and also I thought that there would be more space for the edge labels. But it still doesn't seem to solve the issue. I am also having an issue with the red Arrows. I'd like to bed out of the graph instead of in the same direction, but I cant seem to figure out how to change the arc attribute so that it looks good.

Now it looks like:

[image]

The code I used is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,decorations,automata,backgrounds,petri}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.8]

\begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
    \node (A) at (0,3) {A};
    \node (B) at (3,3) {B};
    \node (C) at (6,3) {C};
    \node (D) at (6,0) {D};
    \node (E) at (6,-3) {E};
    \node (F) at (3,-3) {F};
    \node (G) at (0,-3) {G};
    \node (H) at (0,0) {H};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
              every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
              every edge/.style={draw=black}]

    \draw [red,-] (A.90) arc (0:264:4mm) node[pos=0.2,above left] {$xx$} (A);
    \path [-] (A) edge node {$xx$} (B);
    \path [-] (A) edge[bend left=60] node {$xx$} (C);
    \path [-] (A) edge node {$xx$} (D);
    \path [-] (A) edge node {$xx$} (E);
    \path [-] (A) edge node {$xx$} (F);
    \path [-] (A) edge[bend right=60] node {$xx$} (G);
    \path [-] (A) edge node {$xx$} (H);

    \draw [red,-] (B.90) arc (0:264:4mm) node[pos=0.2,above left] {$xx$} (B);
    \path [-] (B) edge node {$xx$} (C);
    \path [-] (B) edge node {$xx$} (D);
    \path [-] (B) edge node {$xx$} (E);
    \path [-] (B) edge node {$xx$} (F);
    \path [-] (B) edge node {$xx$} (G);
    \path [-] (B) edge node {$xx$} (H);

    \draw [red,-] (C.90) arc (0:264:4mm) node[pos=0.2,above left] {$xx$} (C);
    \path [-] (C) edge node {$xx$} (D);
    \path [-] (C) edge[bend left=60] node {$xx$} (E);
    \path [-] (C) edge node {$xx$} (F);
    \path [-] (C) edge node {$xx$} (G);
    \path [-] (C) edge node {$xx$} (H);

    \draw [red,-] (D.90) arc (0:264:4mm) node[pos=0.2,above left] {$xx$} (D);
    \path [-] (D) edge node {$xx$} (E);
    \path [-] (D) edge node {$xx$} (F);
    \path [-] (D) edge node {$xx$} (G);
    \path [-] (D) edge node {$xx$} (H);

    \draw [red,-] (E.90) arc (0:264:4mm) node[pos=0.2,above left] {$xx$} (E);
    \path [-] (E) edge node {$xx$} (F);
    \path [-] (E) edge[bend left=60] node {$xx$} (G);
    \path [-] (E) edge node {$xx$} (H);

    \draw [red,-] (F.90) arc (0:264:4mm) node[pos=0.2,above left] {$xx$} (F);
    \path [-] (F) edge node {$xx$} (G);
    \path [-] (F) edge node {$xx$} (H);

    \draw [red,-] (G.90) arc (0:264:4mm) node[pos=0.2,above left] {$xx$} (G);
    \path [-] (G) edge node {$xx$} (H);

    \draw [red,-] (H.90) arc (0:264:4mm) node[pos=0.2,above left] {$xx$} (H);

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When trying to scale the whole graph you should look at `transform canvas` (see the fine Manual, section 25.4 in version 3.0.0).

Comment: Use `every node/.style={fill=white,circle,sloped}`.

Comment: Drawing the `(current bounding box)` showed you have less than `\marginparwidth` left with `scale=1`.  Use \noindent or \centering.  You can save some space by labeling the outer arcs with rectangular nodes, or using a clipping rectangle (if you knew how large to make it).